# How to create a template for Pages?

Tags: posts, theme-development, templates, page-template

In Wordpress, when creating a page, it shows some options for Template under Attributes, such as: Default, Links, One column no sidebar, etc.

Is there a way to add more custom templates to show up here? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is just create a new file in your theme root directory. This file must start with following code:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: No Sidebars
 */
```

Name your file, for example, `page_nosidebars.php` and then WP will add `No Sidebars` template to available templates list.

There is nice article about it [Creating Custom Page Templates](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-custom-page-templates/). I think it will help you to create your own.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for child themes?

Comment: @ClickUpvote You haven't mentioned about child themes. Anyway take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946077/cannot-add-custom-page-template-to-my-child-theme

Answer (score 1):

```
You can create your own template for pages. Below link shows the example of creating template.

Url :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

create a php file and save in active theme folder.

<?php
/*
Template Name: Snarfer
*/
?>

i think this may help u for creating template.
```